# How to send ethers from multiple accounts to a single recipient?

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, ethers.js

I want to transfer 1 ETH distributed to three addresses to a single recipient address. How can I achieve this in ethers.js

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum doesn't support multiple senders in a single transaction.