# Is there a walletnotify in Ethereum like bitcoin does and how to perform batch transaction using web3 python?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

I'm working on project for a crypto exchange
I have geth on a server and I'm using python as a programing language to communicate with geth using web3 library
What i want to do is:

1/In bitcoin there's an option called walletnotify that runs a script whenever you get new transaction that is related to your wallet, how a, I supposed to do that in Ethereum?

2/ When I tried to run a small script to loop a **600** Ethereum block and try to get a transaction of specific address it took like 8 minute to do som and it didn't return any results, this is the example:
I did a **deposit to my address A** and I checked **Ethereum scan platform** transaction information, the transaction was on the block **779688**, my geth node was on the current block **779999** so when I run the script I told it to loop f**rom block 779300 to 779900**, it took like 8 minutes and it didn't even return the transaction information although that address had a transaction that happened in between the given interval, while using **api** from Ethereum scan and going from 0 to 9999999 blocks took only 1 second with a results

is this because I'm running the light mode and they are running the full node?

is it because the light mode have to download again the blocks and full node already have the blocks?

this is the script

```
    for x in range(start, end):
    block = w3.eth.getBlock(x, True)
    for transaction in block.transactions:
        if transaction['to'] == address or transaction['from'] == address:
            with open("transactions.pkl", "wb") as f:
                hashStr = transaction['hash'].hex()
                tx_dictionary[hashStr] = transaction
                pickle.dump(tx_dictionary, f)
            f.close()
print(f"Finished searching blocks {start} through {end} and found {len(tx_dictionary)} transactions")
```

3/my last question is, when I generate 5 addresses using web3 python and I deposit some balance to these different addresses, is there a way to do batching transaction to move all the balance to a central address (using web3 python)?

Comment: 1/ There are some alternatives https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/17818, 3/ Unfortunately it is not possible, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83117

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum, you need to check every transaction in each block to determine if it's related to a specific address in order to retrieve all transactions associated with that address. Moreover, if it's a token contract, you have to parse each transaction and analyze the logs provided by get_transaction_receipt to identify if it includes your specified address.

Third-party APIs typically achieve fast retrieval by pre-parsing all transactions and storing them in databases like Elastic Search.